# Handling same screen resolution with different densities for android os version 2.2 in android

Tags: android

Iam developing an application for android device samsung galaxy nexus (1280*720) it comes under normal screen and xhdpi screen density, and for Samsung Nexus s(480*800) it comes under normal screen and hdpi screen density. So where to place the xml layouts for these devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in your android manifest file

```
 <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
         />
```

Comment: My application suuports xlarge(Samsung Galaxy Tab 10 inch(1280*800)),large(HTC EVO 4G 7 inch tablet(1024*600)),normal (Smasung Nexus s(480*800))screens. But present the conflict is that my aaplication must support Samsung Galaxy Nexus(1280*720) which comes under normal screen resolution and xhdpi-density. So how and where (folder like layout-normal,layout-large )to make different layouts for Samsung Galaxy Nexus(1280*720 normal) and Smasung Nexus s(480*800 normal)screens.